# Datatables and tabletools: How to export selected and sorted data to pdf, csv,

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I spend all day looking for a solution on the internet, where need to export data after I have them sorted and selected rows.

I use:

**dataTables 1.10.3**

**tabletools 2.2.3**

In the code, I put the following:

```
$(function(){
        var table = $("#price").dataTable({
            //"order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumnDefs" : [
                {
                "bSortable" : false,
                "aTargets" : [0, 1, 10]
                }
            ]
        });
        var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table, {
            "sSwfPath" : "/files/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "sRowSelect" :   "multi",
            "sRowSelector" : "td:first-child",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "Copy",
                    "mColumns": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "mColumns": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "mColumns": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
                    "bSelectedOnly": true,
                    "oSelectorOpts": {"order": "current"}
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "mColumns": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
                    "oSelectorOpts": { "order": "current"}
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "select_all",
                    "sButtonText": "Sellect all"
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "select_none",
                    "sButtonText": "Desellect all"
                } 
            ]
        } );
        $( ".export-btn" ).append( tableTools.fnContainer());
    });
```

I successfully export selected rows, but they are not sorted. Also I successfully export sorted data, if they are not selected rows.

Is this ever be together? Where I'm wrong?

This is my first time to use datatable and tabletools.

Thank you.